# shared and exclusive locks which will get the data first?

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

Let's say I have the following:

SELECT - Shared Lock -- long running

UPDATE - Exclusive Lock

SELECT - Shared Lock -- long running

These three statements come in order, the first select takes a long time to execute, in this time an update comes and has to wait (conflicting lock), followed by another select (compatible lock). Will the select be allowed to get the row? Or, does the update start a line. If the 2nd (or more) select is allowed to "cut in", and is also long running, will the update end up deadlocked? Is there a way to prevent this, without having to upgrade the select lock to something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each statement comes on its own transaction (ie. separate, conflicting lock namespaces):

No, the third SELECT would not 'cut in' in front of the UPDATE. A lock has to be compatible with **all the locks in the wait list** to be granted. Otherwise the X lock would 'starve'.

There is some smallprint:

- SELECT does not retain long S locks under the default read committed isolation level
- There are some special cases when locks are granted explicitly ahead of the wait list (they 'cut in') but those cases never apply to data locks (ie. select vs. update vs. insert)

See also [SQL Server, Lock Manager, and “relaxed” FIFO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/06/02/sql-server-lock-manager-and-relaxed-fifo.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the great link and explanation.